# Android gradle flavors, sourceset per flavor with multiple srcDirs, force overriding of values/strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This question is a follow up of [Android gradle library resources in product flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758134/android-gradle-library-resources-in-product-flavor)

Came up with a strange issue.

Namely as described in [Android gradle library resources in product flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758134/android-gradle-library-resources-in-product-flavor) when using multiple source sets for each flavor, for res and resources everything works fine, the resources from other directories are merged all together.

Problem:
**The flavor values/strings.xml won't replace the values/strings.xml in the main project**
(This is where i keep the app label and app icon).Because of this behaviour my app icon and title are messed up (not from the flavor).

I found something here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging
(title Handling Multiple Resource Folders) but that does not help me to go further as I don't understand **how to force this specific flavor file to override the other in main project**.

== Edit ==

My project structure and build.gradle (for the main project)

**Project structure**

> - 3rdparty
>
>   - Graphics
>
>     - Iconsets
>
>       - **IconsetBase**
>       - **Iconset1**
>       - **Iconset3**
> - MainProject
>
>   - src
>
>     - **main**    (main project)
>     - **flavor1**
>     - **flavor2**
>     - ...

**build.gradle (main project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    useOldManifestMerger false
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    lintOptions {
       ...
    } 

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
}

signingConfigs {
    ...
}

buildTypes {
    ...
}

// Common dependencies
dependencies {
   compile project(':3rdparty:Graphics:Iconsets:IconsetBase')
}

defaultConfig {
    ...
}

productFlavors {
    flavor1         { packageName "..."}
    flavor2         { packageName "..."}
}

android.sourceSets.flavor1 {
    res {
        srcDirs = ['flavor1','../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/IconsetBase/src/main/res', '../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/Iconset1/src/main/res']
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['flavor1','../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/IconsetBase/src/main/res', '../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/Iconset1/src/main/res']
    }
}
android.sourceSets.flavor2 {
    res {
        srcDirs = ['flavor2','../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/IconsetBase/src/main/res', '../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/Iconset3/src/main/res']
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['flavor2','../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/IconsetBase/src/main/res', '../3rdparty/Graphics/Iconsets/Iconset3/src/main/res']
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
}
```

---

**SOLVED**

Issue was with the MainProject.iml

After adding flavor paths to RES_FOLDERS_RELATIVE_PATH everything worked

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: Sure. See under == Edit ==

Comment: So if you have a main strings.xml and also strings.xml in both your flavors, you can't overwrite it like that.  Get rid of any duplicate strings that are in your main strings.xml because they will never be used, right?  Your main strings.xml should only have strings that will be used by both flavors.

Comment: Sure, but there is a problem. It is the app_name element. If i remove this from the mail strings.xml then I get an error and cannot build.
I tried to remove app_name from main and add it to the other flavors. Does not work

Comment: What kind of error?  I don't have my app_name string in my main strings.xml and it's no problem.

Comment: I use it in my AndroidManifest.xml, @string/app_name appears red. Also : ./Android/MainProject/MainProject/build/manifests/flavor1/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:48: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').

Comment: If you have your directory structure set up properly and defined in your gradle file, the IDE will automatically load resources for your selected build variant.

Comment: When you hover over `@string/app_name` in your manifest file, it should look like this, with your currently selected build variant selected: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8lJ5C.png

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am trying to accomplish the same.